# Custom xml converter with Retrofit 2.0.2 is never called

Tags: android, retrofit

I have to use retrofit 2.0.2 with xml api response. But my custom xml converter is never called.

Playing around with this I found out:

- if I use Volley to parse the same response, the same custom xml converter IS called;
- if I apply GsonConverterFactory to my RestClient and parse json response, my custom JsonAdapter (@JsonAdapter(SomeAdapter.class)) IS called.

Anyone, how make my simple xml converter to be called? Am I doing something wrong, or retrofit 2.0.2 somehow doesn't support simple xml converter.

My java class where I parse response:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.convert.Convert;

public class PassengerResponse {
  @Element
  @Convert(value = SomeConverter.class)
  private String id;
}
```

Custom xml converter that is never called:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.convert.Converter;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputNode;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.OutputNode;

public class SomeConverter implements Converter<String> {
   @Override
   public String read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
    return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void write(OutputNode node, String value) throws Exception {
   }
}
```

My retrofit RestClient:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory;

public class RestClient2 {
private UserApiJSON userPassengerApi;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 120000;
private static RestClient2 INSTANCE;

public static RestClient2 getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new RestClient2();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private RestClient2() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                    .build())
            .build();

    userPassengerApi = retrofit.create(UserApiJSON.class);
}

public UserApiJSON getUserPassengerApi() {
    return userPassengerApi;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your custom converter you have create custom `Converter.Factory`. And than add it to the `retrofit` using method `addConverterFactory()`. Below working example:

```
public class StringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

public static StringConverterFactory create() {
    return new StringConverterFactory();
}

@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (String.class.equals(type)) {
        return new Converter<ResponseBody, String>() {
            @Override
            public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
                return value.string();
            }
        };
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And than add it retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(StringConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build())
        .build();
```

In Retrofit 2 allows multiple converters. There is video by Jake Wharton who talks about [Retrofit 2](https://realm.io/news/droidcon-jake-wharton-simple-http-retrofit-2/) and it features like a multiple converters.

Inside [`Retrofit`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java) class there is a method `nextRequestBodyConverter` which returns converter for appropriate `Type`

Answer (score 7):

Actually [SimpleXmlConverterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/simplexml/SimpleXmlConverterFactory.java) has different method to create its instance.) If all you need is to make your custom Converer(s) work, do the next:

```
Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
    .client(okHttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build())
    .build();
```

Note: if you add different converters, order does metter. Why? Watch Jake Wharton [presentation](https://realm.io/news/droidcon-jake-wharton-simple-http-retrofit-2/).

Answer (score 1):

```
public UsStatesApi providesApi(){

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();

        Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
                .baseUrl("http://www.google.com")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit.create( UsStatesApi.class);

    }
```